# Type checking variables on the sanic context object?

Tags: python, mypy, sanic

The [sanic](https://sanic.dev/en/) python http server provides a [context object](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/request.html#context) for global state. A nice newer feature of python is type checking, which can detect misspelled attributes. Is there a way of telling a type system like mypy what attributes, and their types you want to add to context object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the object is a SimpleNamespace, there is no OOTB way to handle this. But, you have a few alternatives.

First, you can use [Sanic Extensions](https://sanic.dev/en/plugins/sanic-ext/injection.html) to inject an object that is typed.

```py
foo = Foo()

app.ext.dependency(foo)

@app.get("/getfoo")
async def getfoo(request: Request, foo: Foo):
    return text(foo.bar())
```

Second, you could create a custom object that is typed and pass that to Sanic.

```py
class CustomContext:
    foo: int

app = Sanic(..., ctx= CustomContext())


ctx: CustomContext = app.ctx
```

Third, you could subclass the `Sanic` class and provide a typed object.